# Why String.protoptype.charCodeAt() can convert binary string into an Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, utf, typed-arrays

Suppose I have a base64 encoded string and I want to convert it into an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer), I can do it in this way:

```
// base64 decode the string to get the binary data
const binaryString = window.atob(base64EncodedString);

// convert from a binary string to an ArrayBuffer
const buf = new ArrayBuffer(binaryString.length);
const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);   
for (let i = 0, strLen = binaryString.length; i < strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
}

// get ArrayBuffer: `buf`
```

From [String.protoptype.charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), it will return an integer between 0 and 65535 representing the UTF-16 code unit at the given index. But an [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray)'s range value is [0, 255].

I was initially thinking that the code point we obtained from `charCodeAt()` could go out of the bound of the `Uint8Array` range. Then I checked the built-in [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob) function, which returns an ASCII string containing decoded data. According to [Binary Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString/Binary), ASCII string has a range from 0 to 127, which is included in the range of `Uint8Array`, and that's why we are safe to use `charCodeAt()` in this case.

That's my understanding. I'm not sure if I interpret this correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your question? It seems like you've explained how it works.

Comment: You are understanding it correctly. `charCodeAt` is designed to support utf-16. And utf-16 was designed to be compatible with ASCII so the first 256 characters have exact values like in ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like my understanding is correct.

Thanks to @Konrad, and here is his/her add-up:

> charCodeAt is designed to support utf-16. And utf-16 was designed to be compatible with ASCII so the first 256 characters have exact values like in ASCII encoding.